# Azure Container Registry Task: Dokerfile is not getting uploaded to repo using terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-container-registry

Please help me with this:
I was trying to deploy an image into the ACR but it wasn't deploying to the repo. What wrong in the script.
Thank you in advance

```
resource "azurerm_container_registry_task" "example" {
name = "example-task"
container_registry_id = azurerm_container_registry.acr.id
platform {
os = "Linux"
}
docker_step {
dockerfile_path = "/dock/Dockerfile"
context_path = "https://abcxyz.blob.core.windows.net/dock/Dockerfile"
context_access_token = "?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiyx&se=2022-12-12T13:44:59Z&st=2022-12-12T05:44:59Z&spr=https&sig=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz%3D"
image_names = ["${azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/flagcont:latest"]
push_enabled = true
target = "${azurerm_container_registry.acr.login_server}/flagcont:latest"
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @yashwanth babu could you post error message? we can understand more information.

Comment: @Venkatesan "no error" it is deploying but image is not created in repo. My docker file contains the following script:
FROM scratch
ADD hello /
CMD ["/hello"]

hello is my binary executable file. It gives you the "flag" value when you run the image.

Also, I notice that this "example-task" is created in "Tasks". But I am trying to build the image using the Dockerfile and push it to Registry repo.